# Installing pyside on Fedora 19

Tags: fedora, python

I'm trying to install pyside from source on Fedora 19. Running `sudo python setup.py bdist_egg --version=1.2.0 --qmake=/usr/lib64` gives:

```
HEAD is now at 92062bc... Version bump to 0.2.14
Checking out submodule pyside-examples to branch master
Running process: git checkout master
Already on 'master'
Removing /home/andreas/pyside-setup/pyside_package
running bdist_egg
running build
Python architecture is 64bit
error: Permission denied
```

And without sudo:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 228, in <module>
    rmtree(d)
  File "/home/andreas/pyside-setup/utils.py", line 280, in rmtree
    shutil.rmtree(dirname, ignore_errors=False, onerror=handleRemoveReadonly)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/shutil.py", line 247, in rmtree
    rmtree(fullname, ignore_errors, onerror)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/shutil.py", line 256, in rmtree
    onerror(os.rmdir, path, sys.exc_info())
  File "/home/andreas/pyside-setup/utils.py", line 276, in handleRemoveReadonly
    os.chmod(path, stat.S_IRWXU| stat.S_IRWXG| stat.S_IRWXO) # 0777
OSError: [Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/home/andreas/pyside-setup/pyside_package/PySide'
```

Comment: Do `/home/andreas/pyside-setup/pyside_package/PySide` has the executable bit?

Comment: What is the executable bit? What do you mean?

Comment: "Software and software installers in GNU/Linux need to be marked as 'executable' in order to be treated as runnable programs." You can do so using `chmod u+x file`

Answer (score 1):

Since the `/home/andreas/pyside-setup/pyside_package/PySide` has not the executable bit, you should set it up. This allows the script to be executed:

```
chmod u+x /home/andreas/pyside-setup/pyside_package/PySide
```

Should allow the execution. Any "executables" files needs this bit or Linux will prevent you from executing. This is one of the security measures of Linux.